Как принять такое уведомление в selenium?
нужно както закрыть или принять это уведомление, знаю что есть параметр запуска для их отключения, а еще есть параметр для их автоматического принятия, но они не работают так как подключаюсь к уже запущенной сессии, а в ней эти параметры тоже почемуто не работают.
точно видел что как-то с ними можно взаимодействовать в pypputter, но как именно не могу найти, может быть через js какойто.
вообщем помогите пж!


Это больше похоже на форму входа чем на уведомление, там же крестик есть, найдите его селектор и сгенерируйте на нем клик мыши примеры

Daniil Loban, к сожалению это так не работает, окно возникает не на html, это внутреннее уведомление хрома и доступ к его коду мы не имеем

Это вход в аккаунт браузера?

Daniil Loban, это уведомление с предложением сохранить пароль в профиле браузера

В реальном браузере это вероятно можно выключить опцией, посмотрите тут возможно найдется что-то подходящее

На аглоязычном ресурсе рекомендуют входить с опцией гостя (гость не использует менеджер паролей) chrome_opt.add_argument("--guest")
